# In Unity2D I am trying to make a simple sprite move with the AddForce method but it is not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and I am trying to call AddForce on the RigidBody to move it but when I press 'a' and 'd', the h value changes correctly, but the player still does not move.

Here is the code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 50f;

    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        rb2d.AddForce((Vector2.right * speed) * h);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your script worked fine for me.  I created a new scene and added a sprite with rigidbody and your script.  It moved horizontal as expected.

Comment: Check that your object has a rigidbody2D attached to it and not a normal rigidbody

Comment: Also check the mass of your rigidbody2D. Make sure it isn't really high.

Comment: I tried all of that. I guess I will just redo the project in case I messed up earlier and made a weird bug. Thanks!

Comment: Note : Make sure you actually need the whole Physics engine power to move your sprite. The engine uses realistic values (mass, distances, etc...) to calculate movements and interactions. And more often than not, using forces to move a playable object usually result in weird moves.